# ASP.NET on Azure and Universal Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config, asp.net-membership

I want to transfer my asp.net webforms app to windows azure and now have problems with membership provider. I installed universal providers as Scott mentioned [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx). As soon as i want to register or login a user i am getting the following error:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'defaultprovider'. Note
>   that attribute names are case-sensitive.
>
> Line 59:  Line 60:  Line 61:        Line 62:
>    Line 63:

this is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

    <connectionStrings>

        [...]
</connectionStrings>

      <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=session;timeout=20;" />
  </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />

        <globalization uiCulture="de" culture="de-DE" />

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>

        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>


        <profile>
            <providers>
          <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider" connectionstringname="ApplicationServices" applicationname="/">
        </add>
        </providers>
    </profile>


      <membership defaultprovider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
           <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider" connectionstringname="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" >
        </add></providers>
      </membership>

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: shouldn't the `defaultprovider` attribute be with capital P, i.e. `defaultProvider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how you ended up with lowercase `defaultprovider`, but according to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1b9hw62f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it should be with capital "P" - `defaultProvider`. Pay attention to the error message which suggests that the attribute names are case-sensitive!

Comment: Had the same thing today. It's Scott Hanselman's article that I copypasted the line from.